# Data extension is not available in SFMC contact configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am trying to create a Journey builder activity but before that we need to create a contact configuration.But i don't get the Data extension in the contact configuration and the Data extension is also enabled as root data extension.I have created journey builder activity in previous but did not face this issue.Could someone help me in guiding what i am missing in this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the new release, You have to create [Population](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_designer/create_a_population/) for one to one relationship and once you configure population with your DataExtension then immediately, your DE set to be Use as root and mapping field would come in contact configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response after creating population i got the DE enabled as Root.Previously i have used Data designer for establishing root data and data relationships.

Comment: I have two more DE which are one to many relationship .Previously i was able to create all relationship in Data designer.But now i am not able to create relationship in a single attribute group.Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: you can use data designer for one to many relationship. Population just only for 1:1 relationship.